# Many-to-Many class relationship in UML diagram

Tags: uml

What is the relationship of many-to-many in UML?
for example : if one-to-one relationship is call composition
                 one-to-many relationship is call aggregation
is that association? or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is (almost) no link between cardinality of an association and its aggregation kind (none, composite, aggregation).

Each association end has a lower bound (minimum cardinality) an upper bound (maximum cardinality) and an aggregation kind.
Some combinations are impossible but you a can have a "one-to-one" association with or without composition.

EDIT : add examples

All these associations are valid.
For example association between MyClass3 and MyClass4 is *one-to-one* and composite (end3).
While, association between MyClass11 and MyClass12 is *ont-to-many* and composite (end11).
Association between MyClass and MyClass2 is *one-to-one" but not composite.

[image]

You can make a copy of this model [here](http://app.genmymodel.com/genmymodel?clonedProject=_9d57wNfmEDCfIYZ117xuEQ)

Comment: Erm...I still don't understand what you mean....

Comment: I have add an example. I hope this can help you to understand.